# My main.storyboard is not showing up on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So here are the steps that I do when opening Xcode to make a basic application. I first click on "create a new Xcode project" then I tap on "single view app" for "ios" then I fill out the information such as the name of the app and if I want to use core data etc.. and when I finish and tap on "create" I see no main.storyboard on the left side navigation panel... I do not know if I am doing something right. I initially did everything on the LaunchScreen.storyboard, but when I did something it did not allow me because something called segues..

Comment: I think you are using `SwiftUI`. I will suggest you create a new project and when you have to add the name of the app and select the core data, then at the bottom you will see `User Interface`. Make sure you select `storyboard` and now `SwiftUI`.

Comment: You are using SwiftUI i guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select Storyboard in User Interface as shown in the image

[image]

Comment: omg haha this was all.. i am dumb!! Ok, so do you know how to change from the User Interface from SwiftUI to storyboard

Comment: Delete the project and create a new one ;)

Comment: ufff i tried that... but XCode is like "you can only create 10 apps in a 7 day period" because I kept deleting it several times and making new ones hahah

Answer (score 0):

Please, select **storyboard** instead of **SwiftUI**, as with *XCODE 11* by ***default*** the value of User Interface is set to SwiftUI and it doesn't include storyboard.